# Understanding journal log when USB stick inserted (recover dead USB stick)

Tags: usb, data-recovery, logs

I have an USB stick which can't be mounted anymore. In fact it is worse since it doesn't appear in Disk Utility. Nevertheless, it seems to be detected as an USB device but not as a storage device... Here are the logs from the Console app which contains USB in it:

```
error   20:13:28.917730+0200    kernel  AppleUSBXHCIDevice: AppleUSBXHCIDevice::transferEvent: no endpoint 1 for event 0x0000000000200d00 1b000000 0e018001
default 20:13:28.920350+0200    kernel  HS08@14300000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0xffff/1201/0000 (IOUSBHostDevice / 14) at 480 Mbps
error   20:13:28.920366+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: controller <private> (XHC1) usbServiceArray <private>(count 1) options 0x00000000
error   20:13:28.920371+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: [0] <private>
error   20:13:28.920372+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (IOUSBHostDevice) options 0x00000000
error   20:13:28.920388+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
error   20:13:28.920392+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (IOUSBHostDevice)
error   20:13:28.920402+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::addDeviceToUsbPlane:
error   20:13:28.920658+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: usbServiceCallbackGated completed with 0x00000000 and service <private>
error   20:13:28.920665+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering IOUSBHostDevice@14300000 (<private>) for matching
default 20:13:28.982536+0200    kernel  IOUSBHostDevice@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::setConfigurationGated: AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice selected configuration 1
error   20:13:28.982693+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: controller <private> (XHC1) usbServiceArray <private>(count 1) options 0x00000000
error   20:13:28.982698+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: [0] <private>
error   20:13:28.982702+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (IOUSBHostInterface) options 0x00000000
error   20:13:28.982990+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
error   20:13:28.983000+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostInterface <private> (IOUSBHostInterface)
default 20:13:28.983040+0200    kernel  USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0xffff 0x1201 0x0
error   20:13:28.983302+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: usbServiceCallbackGated completed with 0x00000000 and service <private>
error   20:13:28.983412+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering AppleUSBInterface@0 (<private>) for matching
error   20:13:28.986315+0200    com.apple.ifdreader Failed to find AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID.
error   20:13:28.987839+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
default 20:13:28.992888+0200    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[0] to com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver
default 20:13:29.082493+0200    icdd                   Added | 0x10000058 - [USB][     IOUSBHostDevice ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14300000 |
default 20:13:29.097088+0200    icdd                Inferior | 0x10000059 - [USB][     IOUSBHostDevice ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14300000 |
default 20:13:29.199131+0200    airportd    SC: <airport[220]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/SmartCCADesenseUSBPresence'
```

It tried to compare the logs from this USB stick and another working one. Here are the logs from a working USB stick:

```
error   20:21:12.618896+0200    kernel  AppleUSBXHCIDevice: AppleUSBXHCIDevice::transferEvent: no endpoint 1 for event 0x0000000000200000 1b000000 10018000
default 20:21:12.632163+0200    kernel  HS08@14300000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0x058f/6387/0105 (GOODRAM 2GB / 16) at 480 Mbps
error   20:21:12.632183+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: controller <private> (XHC1) usbServiceArray <private>(count 1) options 0x00000000
error   20:21:12.632186+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: [0] <private>
error   20:21:12.632189+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (GOODRAM 2GB) options 0x00000000
error   20:21:12.632204+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
error   20:21:12.632206+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (GOODRAM 2GB)
error   20:21:12.632217+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::addDeviceToUsbPlane:
error   20:21:12.632565+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: usbServiceCallbackGated completed with 0x00000000 and service <private>
error   20:21:12.632575+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering GOODRAM 2GB@14300000 (<private>) for matching
default 20:21:12.701512+0200    kernel  GOODRAM 2GB@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::setConfigurationGated: AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice selected configuration 1
error   20:21:12.701756+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: controller <private> (XHC1) usbServiceArray <private>(count 1) options 0x00000000
error   20:21:12.701764+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: [0] <private>
error   20:21:12.701772+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (IOUSBHostInterface) options 0x00000000
error   20:21:12.701792+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
error   20:21:12.701797+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostInterface <private> (IOUSBHostInterface)
default 20:21:12.701834+0200    kernel  USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 15030356004103 0x58f 0x6387 0x105, 2
error   20:21:12.702518+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: usbServiceCallbackGated completed with 0x00000000 and service <private>
error   20:21:12.702550+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering AppleUSBInterface@0 (<private>) for matching
error   20:21:12.705179+0200    com.apple.ifdreader Failed to find AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID.
error   20:21:12.708615+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
default 20:21:12.715265+0200    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[0] to com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver
default 20:21:12.833878+0200    icdd                   Added | 0x10000061 - [USB][         GOODRAM 2GB ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14300000 |
default 20:21:12.835072+0200    icdd                Inferior | 0x10000062 - [USB][         GOODRAM 2GB ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14300000 |
default 20:21:12.897186+0200    airportd    SC: <airport[220]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/SmartCCADesenseUSBPresence'
default 20:21:14.450107+0200    Finder  <<<Query Result from client cache (u: 3, ET: 0.027604766): "/System/Volumes/Data : 9.71 GB,/Volumes/USB DISK : 0 Bytes"
default 20:21:14.450176+0200    Finder  CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_PURGEABLE : {
    "/System/Volumes/Data" = 9705231212;
    "/Volumes/USB DISK" = 0;
}
default 20:21:14.450319+0200    Finder  CACHE_DELETE_PURGEABLE_BY_CONTAINER : {
    disk1 =     {
        "/System/Volumes/Data" =         {
            "CACHE_DELETE_AMOUNT" = 9705231212;
            "CACHE_DELETE_SHARED_PURGEABLE" = 9705231212;
        };
    };
    disk2 =     {
        "/Volumes/USB DISK" =         {
            "CACHE_DELETE_AMOUNT" = 0;
        };
    };
}
default 20:21:14.450526+0200    Finder  CacheDeleteCopyPurgeableSpaceWithInfo result for all volumes : {
    "CACHE_DELETE_CACHED_RESULT" = 1;
    "CACHE_DELETE_ELAPSED_TIME" = "0.027604766";
    "CACHE_DELETE_PURGEABLE_BY_CONTAINER" =     {
        disk1 =         {
            "/System/Volumes/Data" =             {
                "CACHE_DELETE_AMOUNT" = 9705231212;
                "CACHE_DELETE_SHARED_PURGEABLE" = 9705231212;
            };
        };
        disk2 =         {
            "/Volumes/USB DISK" =             {
                "CACHE_DELETE_AMOUNT" = 0;
            };
        };
    };
    "CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_PURGEABLE" =     {
        "/System/Volumes/Data" = 9705231212;
        "/Volumes/USB DISK" = 0;
    };
}
default 20:21:14.460921+0200    Finder  <<<Query Result from client cache (u: 3, ET: 0.009099481): "/Volumes/USB DISK : 0 Bytes"
default 20:21:14.462888+0200    Finder  CACHE_DELETE_VOLUME : /Volumes/USB DISK
default 20:21:14.569587+0200    storagekitd <<<Query Result from client cache (u: 3, ET: 0.052167255): "/Volumes/USB DISK : 0 Bytes"
```

Notice that the first 25 lines are the same (the names and the hex numbers are the only differences). Therefore there is no error message telling why it failed..

Do you have any idea of the health of this USB stick according to the logs ? Is it only the flash part which is dead (because my computer and the stick seems to manage to talk in USB) ? Do you have any idea of how to recover it (maybe with a physical intervention) ?

Comment: You should also look at all kinds of error messages starting from the time you connected your suspicious USB stick. There may be errors which are not at the USB communication level.

Comment: Could you check your suspicious USB stick is seen at the physical level: [↵][alt]+ > System Information… > Hardware > USB?

Answer (score 0):

Only suggestion might be to take your USB (if the contents is important) to a computer engineer or use some data recovery software.